# Laravel redirect from controller gives "method is not supported for this route" error

Tags: laravel, redirect, methods, routes, put

I have a route that supports PUT:

```
Route::put('/products/{id}/cancel/', 'ProductController@cancel')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

After the Controller updates the state of the product it should redirect to another route:

```
return redirect('products')->with('success', 'Produto cancelado');
```

that points to

```
Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@list')->name('products');
```

All is working until the Redirect.
The product is updated but the redirect gives a method not supported error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD
```

I've also tried the following redirects:

```
return redirect('/products/')->with('success', 'Produto cancelado');
```

and

```
return redirect()->route('products')->with('success', 'Produto cancelado');
```

How is the method PUT passed? Should I explicitly invoke the GET method in the redirect?

How should I solve this?

---

EDIT:
I'm sending the PUT from a HTTPrequest. So I'm returning to the JS function. I want to forward to a view that accepts the with->.

---

EDIT2:
I can return a view but it only appears on the network>preview of the Developer Tools.

```
return view('pages.products')->with('success', 'Produto cancelado');
```

But I need it in the window obviously.

I could redirect in the js but that way I miss showing the flash messages in the partial blade.

---

I don't know what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the GET method. the error says put method is not supported

```
Route::put('/products/{id}/cancel/', 'ProductController@cancel')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

If you try this as `domainname.com/products/5/cancel` then define it as below.

```
Route::get('products/{id}/cancel', 'ProductController@cancel')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: I want PUT to get to @cancel.

That is correct and is working correctly.

I also want GET to get to 'products'.

I don't know why it uses the PUT in the redirect to the GET

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing some cheating:

I added a new PUT route:

```
Route::put('/products', 'ProductController@list')->name('products_put');
```

the controller returns:

```
return redirect()->route('products')->with('success', 'Produto cancelado',200);
```

and the reponse handler does the cheating:

```
document.write(this.responseText);
window.history.pushState('products', 'eBaw · online shopping', '/products');
```